# Python SQL Insert script

Tags: python, sql

I'm creating a Python script to insert some records in a table, but have the following problem:

```
 INSERT INTO  orders VALUES (7656940929251, "ADIDAS | KID'S STAN SMITH")
,(242345235233, 'ADIDAS | CLASSIC BACKPACK')
```

I get the error: "Invalid column name 'ADIDAS | KID'S STAN SMITH'

How can I fix this with Python?

Comment: place all the above query in triple quotes """ your query  """

Comment: I tried but not working :(

Comment: Share what you have tried after my comment ?

Comment: ~insert_sql = f"""INSERT INTO products VALUES {str(tuples_v3)}"""~

Comment: insert_sql=f"INSERT INTO  orders VALUES ({tuples_v3[0]},'{tuples_v3[1]}' ) " use this syntax

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say this is your tuple:

```
tuples_v3s = ((7656941224163, 'ADIDAS | CLASSIC BACKPACK'),
             (7656941256931, 'ADIDAS | CLASSIC BACKPACK | LEGEND INK MULTICOLOUR'),
             (7656940929251, "ADIDAS | KID'S STAN SMITH"))
for tuples_v3 in tuples_v3s:
  print(f"""INSERT INTO  orders VALUES ({tuples_v3[0]},'{tuples_v3[1].replace("'","''")}' ) """)

#INSERT INTO  orders VALUES (7656941224163,'ADIDAS | CLASSIC BACKPACK' ) 
#INSERT INTO  orders VALUES (7656941256931,'ADIDAS | CLASSIC BACKPACK | LEGEND INK MULTICOLOUR' ) 
#INSERT INTO  orders VALUES (7656940929251,'ADIDAS | KID''S STAN SMITH' )
```

Comment: It works, but when I change the tuples_v3 to: "ADIDAS | KID'S STAN SMITH"

Then I have the following error: Incorrect syntax near 'S'

Comment: The problem you are stating is including apostrophe in name in insert for that double single quotes are used. Now check the solution.

Comment: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I have run the above snippet on google colab and I have attached the output I am getting. Where are you getting this error ?

Comment: Please check the variable name i have used difference of __s__ you might have replaced it into your code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

If you are using psycopg2, Please update your query as below

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO products VALUES (7656941224163, %s), 
                        (7656941256931, %s),
                        (7656940929251, %s)"
cur.execute(insert_query, ("ADIDAS | CLASSIC BACKPACK", "ADIDAS | CLASSIC BACKPACK | LEGEND INK MULTICOLOUR", "ADIDAS | KID'S STAN SMITH"))
```

Comment: Using the MSSQLOperator from Airflow,.

Comment: Your error is updated now. It is showing as invalid column name. Could you please provide the details of the table you are trying to insert data into

Comment: Try below:
val = "ADIDAS | KID'S STAN SMITH"
query = f"""" INSERT INTO  orders VALUES (7656940929251, {val}""")

Comment: Error : Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'S STAN SMITH)